# Блок поделиться на сайте магазине

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

на сайте магазине на страницах товара есть блок поделиться при клике на поделиться в facebook загружается логотип сайта, а не картинка товара, как это исправить ?
на остальных соц сетях появляется как бы слайдер в котором можно переключить картинку с логотипа на картинку товара. Почему вообще лого туда грузится ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta property="og:image" content="//image-url.png">
```